# Vowpal Wabbit ignore linear terms, only keep interaction terms

Tags: feature-selection, interaction, vowpalwabbit

Hi have a Vowpal Wabbit file with two namespaces, for example:

```
1.0 |A snow |B ski:10
0.0 |A snow |B walk:10
1.0 |A clear |B walk:10
0.0 |A clear |B walk:5
1.0 |A clear |B walk:100
1.0 |A clear |B walk:15
```

Using -q AB, I can get the interaction terms. Is there any way for me to keep only the interaction terms and ignore the linear terms?

In other words, the result of `vw sample.vw -q AB --invert_hash sample.model` right now is this:

```
....
A^clear:24861:0.153737
A^clear^B^walk:140680:0.015292
A^snow:117127:0.126087
A^snow^B^ski:21312:0.015803
A^snow^B^walk:28234:-0.010592
B^ski:107733:0.015803
B^walk:114655:0.007655
Constant:116060:0.234153
```

I would like it to be something like this:

```
....
A^clear^B^walk:140680:0.015292
A^snow^B^ski:21312:0.015803
A^snow^B^walk:28234:-0.010592
Constant:116060:0.234153
```

The --keep and --ignore options do not produce the desired effect because they are appear to be considered before the quadratic terms are generated. Is it possible to do this with vw or do I need a custom preprocessing step that creates all of the combinations?

Comment: Is there a good motivating reason for ignoring lower order features?

Comment: @MartinPopel If you want to use VW to generate a "pure" matrix factorization model, you'd want to exclude the linear terms and only use the low rank quadratic features for making predictions.

Comment: @MartinPopel And I would add that for some prediction models I've trained before, the interaction terms (such as between user and features) improve performance, not having the features all together gives okay performance, and including the features but with no interactions give the worst performance. So it makes sense to remove the linear features and include only the interaction features.

Answer (score 4):

John Langford (the main author of VW) wrote:
There is not a good way to do this at present. The easiest approach 
would be to make `--ignore` apply to the `foreach_feature<>` template in the 
source code.

You can use a trick with transforming each original example into four new examples:

```
1  |first:1  foo bar gah |second:1  loo too rah
-1 |first:1  foo bar gah |second:-1 loo too rah
1  |first:-1 foo bar gah |second:-1 loo too rah
-1 |first:-1 foo bar gah |second:1  loo too rah
```

This makes the quadratic features all be perfectly correlated with the 
label, but the linear features have zero correlation with the label. 
Hence a mild l1 regularization should kill off the linear features.

I'm skeptical that this will improve performance enough to care (hence 
the design), but if you do find that it's useful, please tell us about it.

See the original posts:

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/topics/2964
https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/topics/4346